# Running until loop on a flattened data structure in Ansible

Tags: ansible, until-loop

I am trying to run an ansible "uri" task that fetches the status in an "until" loop till the status returned is either SUCCESS or FAILED. My task looks like this:

```
- name: Fetching recycle status
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ restarter }}/status?job_id={{ item }}"
    method: GET
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Accept: 'application/json'
    return_content: yes
  register: restart_status
  with_items:
     - 14502414
     - 14552415
  until: (restart_status.results|json_query('[*].json')| json_query('[*][*].status')|flatten) in ['SUCCESS', 'FAILED']
```

**restart_status** is a variable that contains the json payload that is returned and it looks like this:

```
{
        "changed": false,
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "item": 14502414,
                "json": [
                    {
                        "created_date": 1635348569000,
                        "job": {
                            "application_name": "testapp",
                            "id": 14552414,
                            "user": "gui"
                        },
                        "status": "FAILED"
                    }
                ],
                "vary": "Accept-Encoding"
            },
            {
                "_ansible_ignore_errors": null,
                "item": 14552415,
                "json": [
                    {
                        "created_date": 1635348569000,
                        "job": {
                            "application_name": "testapp",
                            "id": 14502415,
                            "user": "gui"
                        },
                        "status": "FAILED"
                    }
                ],
                "vary": "Accept-Encoding"
            }
        ]
    }
```

The output of **(restart_status.results|json_query('[*].json')| json_query('[*][*].status')|flatten) is**

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "FAILED",
        "FAILED"
    ]
}
```

I somehow cant seem to get the until clause to work.I have tried multiple things like "contain", "in" ,"not in", ==, but none of it is working. This is the error that is thrown.

```
TASK [Fetching recycle status] **************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '(restart_status.results|json_query('[*].json')| json_query('[*][*].status')|flatten) not in ['INIT', 'PROGRESS']' failed. The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if (restart_status.results|json_query('[*].json')| json_query('[*][*].status')|flatten) not in ['INIT', 'PROGRESS'] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): 'NoneType' object is not iterable"}
```

Any help or pointer to what I am doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *until* is testing the condition on each iteration, i.e. you have to test *restart_status*. Do not test *restart_status.results* which is the cumulative list of all results. Test it on a simpler example first.

Comment: You say that you want to run the task ``" till the status returned is either SUCCESS or FAILED"``. Both iterations in the *results* are *FAILED*. Just to be sure, is this the expected result?

Comment: yes. That is expected. It can be both successes, both failures or a combination of the two.

Answer (score 0):

Since the JSON response you receive contains a list in `json[].status` as shown in `debug` output, the multiple (dynamic) items of that list cannot be matched with `in ['SUCCESS', 'FAILED']`.

However matching the desired status would work, like `'SUCCESS' in ['SUCCESS', 'FAILED']`. If we want to match multiple statuses, we can use `and`/`or` combination.

Something like:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: Fetching recycle status
      until: |
        'SUCCESS' in restart_status.results | json_query('[].json[].status') or
        'FAILED' in restart_status.results | json_query('[].json[].status')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I still get the same error  with the code below                                                                                                        - name: Fetching recycle status
  uri:
    url: "http://{{ restarter }}/status?job_id={{ item }}"
    method: GET
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Accept: 'application/json'
    return_content: yes
  register: restart_status
  with_items:
     - 14502414
     - 14552415
  until: |
    'FAILED' in restart_status.results|json_query('[].json[].status')

Comment: The error posted in question relates to using conditions with `NoneType`, which is not what the `debug` output shows. Using the same data structure, I'm able to match these conditions. Is it the same error as before?

Answer (score 0):

Do not test the cumulative *results*. Using *until* you have to test the registered variable in each iteration, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command: echo FAILED
      register: status
      loop: [1,2,3]
      until: status.stdout in ['FAILED', 'SUCCESS']
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ status.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
```

This trivial example will pass the iterations. Change the command to e.g. "echo XXX". You'll see the *until* condition in action.

---

In your case, the condition might be

```yaml
      until: restart_status.json.0.status in ['FAILED', 'SUCCESS']
```

, but I'm not sure why the attribute *json* is a list. Maybe it keeps the results from all attempts? Anyway, to be on the safe side, the condition below should work also with multiple items in the list

```yaml
      until: restart_status.json|
             json_query('[].status')|unique|
             intersect(['FAILED', 'SUCCESS'])|length > 0
```